# How to implement common watch function to applicable for all controller in angular js

Tags: angularjs

If the `service` throws error, I want to show error page show am updating error variable `$scope.error=true` and navigate to error page 
I am implementing watch function for error variable and navigating to error page.

Can anybody tell me, how to implement common watch function to applicable for all `controller` in `angularjs`.In my application I am handing service error .I am calling `service` in every `controller`.Instead of implementing watch in every `controller`.I want to implement in parent `controller`

Thanks

Comment: The question is not clear enough. Please rephrase the question with possible examples.

Answer (score 0):

if the purpose is navigate to error page, i think better solution is use events.

In you service you can broadcast error.

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('myComponent.error', {
  message: 'some error message';
});
```

And elsewhere (typically in application/routing settings) you can react for it

```
$scope.$on('myComponent.error', function (event, data) {
 console.log(data);
 // show message, redirect or something else
```

});

This solution is better than watch, because you not need dirty every controller and unnecessarily create additional watcher.